# Automatic substitution of sms webOTP does not work on huawei phones

Tags: android, react-native, sms

Automatic substitution of sms webOTP does not work on huawei phones .On all other phones, android works as required. The necessary tags are registered, Please help me

I tried to do everything as in the documentation about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebOTP_API